# Implementation of conditional statement in x86 assembly

Tags: if-statement, assembly, x86, masm

I would like to know how to implement this lines of code into x86 masm assembly:

```
    if (x >= 1 && x <= 100) {
        printsomething1();
    } else if (x >= 101 && x <= 200) {
        printsomething2();
    } else {
        printsomething3();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd break it into contiguous ranges, (assuming x is unsigned) like:

- x is 0, do printsomething3()
- x is 1 to 100, do nothing printsomething1()
- x is 101 to 200, do nothing printsomething2()
- x is 201 or higher, do nothing printsomething3()

Then work from lowest to highest, like:

```
    ;eax = x;

    cmp eax,0
    je .printsomething3
    cmp eax,100
    jbe .printsomething1
    cmp eax,200
    jbe .printsomething2
    jmp .printsomething3
```

If the only difference is the string they print (and not the code they use to print it) I'd go one step further:

```
    mov esi,something3     ;esi = address of string if x is 0
    cmp eax,0
    je .print
    mov esi,something1     ;esi = address of string if x is 1 to 100
    cmp eax,100
    jbe .print
    mov esi,something2     ;esi = address of string if x is 101 to 200
    cmp eax,200
    jbe .print
    mov esi,something3     ;esi = address of string if x is 201 or higher
    jmp .print
```

Comment: upvoted, but you're assuming that `x` is unsigned.  I guess that's equivalent in this case, because any negative will be a large unsigned number above 200.  If you start with `sub eax, 1`, then you can use unsigned-compare for the ranges (`cmp eax,99` and `cmp eax,199`) and avoid one `jcc`, though.  eax=0 will wrap to a large unsigned value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a decent C compiler, you can compile it into assembly language.  For `gcc` use the -S flag:

```
gcc test.c -S
```

This creates the file test.s which contains the assembly language output which can be assembled and linked if needed.

For example, to make your code compile successfully, I rewrote it slightly to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printsomething (int y)
{
    printf ("something %d", y);
}

void func (int x)
{
    if (x >= 1 && x <= 100)
        printsomething(1);
    else
    if (x >= 101  && x <= 200)
        printsomething(2);
    else
        printsomething(3);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x = 0;
    if (argc > 1)
        x = atoi (argv [1]);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles into this assembler:

```
    .file   "s.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "something %d"
    .text
    .globl  printsomething
    .type   printsomething, @function
printsomething:
.LFB5:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE5:
    .size   printsomething, .-printsomething
    .globl  func
    .type   func, @function
func:
.LFB6:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    cmpl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jle .L3
    cmpl    $100, -4(%rbp)
    jg  .L3
    movl    $1, %edi
    call    printsomething
    jmp .L4
.L3:
    cmpl    $100, -4(%rbp)
    jle .L5
    cmpl    $200, -4(%rbp)
    jg  .L5
    movl    $2, %edi
    call    printsomething
    jmp .L4
.L5:
    movl    $3, %edi
    call    printsomething
.L4:
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE6:
    .size   func, .-func
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB7:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    cmpl    $1, -20(%rbp)
    jle .L7
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    addq    $8, %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    atoi
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
.L7:
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE7:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Examine the `func:` part of it and you'll see how it sets up the comparisons with 1, 100, 101, etc.

Comment: Compiling without optimization does not make nice human-readable code, and you didn't even strip out the .cfi directives ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)).  You wrote a function that takes an arg, so it won't optimize away with `-O3`.  You should use at least `-O1`.  "go ask a compiler" is the right answer, but this is barely more helpful than a comment + a Godbolt link.

Comment: @PeterCordes:  Considering spirit of the question, providing tools and a path for the OP to tinker and find the answer seemed more appropriate than literally answering the question.

Comment: Right, but if you're going to do that, compile with `-O3` and maybe comment the asm.  Because `-O0` output is *not* how you should do it.  So you *haven't* shown the OP how to help themself in a useful way.